# Fast Loop Cut in 2.8

Tags: add-on

I found a video @ https://www.linkedin.com/learning/blender-tips-tricks-and-techniques/use-the-mesh-edit-tools-add-on (see video at time 2:02) that shows a really nice loop cutting tool called "Fast Loop" (NOTE: see edit at bottom of this post - this tool doesn't do what I originally thought).

The addon is called "Mesh edit tools 2", and the video author mentions it ships with 2.79. I have 2.8, which has "Mesh Edit Tools" included, but no mention of "#2", and I don't see this really useful loop cutting tool anywhere.

Does anyone know anything about this? Is this version available for Blender 2.8? Or is this fast loop tool still available in the version that exists now?

If anyone is having trouble seeing the tool in the video, it essentially allows you to skip the loop slide part of creating a loop. The loop is instantly created wherever your mouse is. So you can literally click, click, click. Seems like this would be a really nice feature. Especially on those very long edges where you can't even see where your loop is being created until you slide it some distance.

If there is some way to pull off something similar in 2.8, that would be great too.

**Edit**: After watching the video more closely, it appears this addon did *not* instantly create loops where the mouse is hovering. The gentleman in the video is actually sliding loops by holding down the mouse button.

So I'm looking for something that may not exist at all. A loop cutting tool that instantly slides to where the mouse is hovering. Imagine a situation like this one..
[image: loop cut on long box]
So the user cannot see the center of the box they are adding a loop to because they are zoomed in too close. This happens often when working on longer low poly models like boards and sticks. In order to create a loop cut where the orange edge loop is, the user must create it off-screen, and very slowly (because the slide factor resolution increases as you zoom closer) slide it over into view. What I'm hoping for is a way (addon or feature) to instantly create a loop exactly where the mouse is hovering. So there would be no sliding involved. The preview would show the user where the loop will be cut, so there would never be a need to slide them.

Anyone know if something like this is possible? Any idea how difficult it would be to write a tool like this? I know very little about Python, but I have C++ programming experience. Seems like the hardest aspect of creating something like this would probably be calculating the slide factor based on the mouse cursor location.

Thanks again for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need any addon for it in 2.8. You just select Loop Cut on the left side bar and each time you click, new loop cut appears. Then you can hold down the mouse button to slide new loop but as a default it stays in place and you can keep clicking and adding loops.
[image]

Comment: Right, but that is the normal loop cut, right? Where it creates the loop in the exact center of the edges where the mesh is hovered/clicked? If I'm not mistaken, the "Fast Loop" version (in the video) previews and creates the loop exactly where the mouse is hovered, so the user doesn't need to slide it at all to get it where they want it.

Comment: You know what - after watching it again, he may be holding down the button to slide loops. I was under the impression that it was showing a preview of where the loop will be created when they were moving around, but it may be normal sliding.