# How to loop-cut *beyond* the middle?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I often am using the following sequence in Edit mode...

- Loop Cut (snaps the *planned* cut location to the middle when moving the mouse)
- Move (moves the *performed* cut location)

...which effectively moves the cut position *beyond* the middle *after* the cut was performed.

I wonder if there is single-step replacement operation, where the *planned* cut position of the Loop Cut operation is *not snapping* to the middle when moving the mouse, but followes exactly the moving mouse tip (just as the later Move would do)?

That would spare me a lot of mode switching while editing, hence would me much more fluent to work with.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: I don't really understand that question. If you loop cut, you use Ctrl-R to initiate the loop, then left-click once and the loop follows the mouse until you left-click again to set the loop position. How else would you want that to work?

Comment: @JohnEason I think he'd like the planned loop cut to show where his mouse cursor is on the object, rather than have it pop up at the middle of the relevant faces for it to then be dragged where it has to be.

I think [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149287/fast-loop-cut-in-2-8) describes the same problem.

Comment: @Zoukeau Ok, but that's just the way loop cutting works (and the most convenient way as far as I'm concerned). It only takes a second or so to move it exactly where you want and set it in place with another click.

Comment: Additionally to what @JohnEason said that it's very quickly done so I don't see the need to change it either because I prefer to have the cut exactly in the middle without any effort - if I have the cut line somewhere where the mouse is placed I think it's harder to find the middle so I prefer that as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you all for your kind comments. They were very useful. I learned that I must not use all uppercase and edited my posting, to not get recognized as being shouting or rude. I learned that Blender's UI on Windows does not work like other Windows software, and certainly do accept that. Please vote for my answer, so other Windows users learn how this works like. NB: Windows typical usage is to hold CTRL pressed if no snapping-to-middle is wanted instead of holding left mouse button like Blender does. Thanks to everybody! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender 3.4.1's default settings on Windows works like this:

- Initiate loop-cut tool either by pressing Ctrl+R or by clicking on the menu item / menu icon.
- Press the left mouse button *and keep it pressed* while moving the mouse; the *intended* cut position follows the mouse movement.
- When at the *intended* cut position, release the left mouse button; releasing will perform the cut.

*Note: This is not how the majority of applications work on Windows, but it is consistent with how other Blender functionality works on Windows. On Windows, other software moves the intended cut positiony directly after enabling a tool (without pressing the mouse button; pressing it down will perform the cut in those applications).*